How do I Get JFrame to Display JPanel Text Content Even When Called by Action Event?
I have a simple JFrame dialog, that should display "Please Wait" message while the main program completes other activities (which may take anywhere from 30 seconds to more than 10 minutes):
public JFrame waitDialog() {
         JFrame wait = new JFrame();
         wait.setTitle("My Dialog");
         wait.setAlwaysOnTop(true); 
         wait.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
         wait.setSize(300, 150);
         wait.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
         wait.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         String msg = "Plase Wait...";
         wait.add(new JLabel(msg), BorderLayout.CENTER);
         return wait;
    }

When I call it within  the program flow, it works fine:
     ...
     JFrame wait = waitDialog();
     wait.setVisisble(true);
     for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
         // Other activities
         System.out.println(i);
     }
     wait.setVisisble(false);
     ...

However, if I use execute this dialog via an ActionEvent (I click a "Do Other Activities" button on the main application JFrame), even though I use the EXACT SAME CODE to call waitDialog(), the dialog displays without any text. It displays an empty dialog without the  "Please Wait..." message:
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action){
     if (action.getSource==waitforit) {
         runWait(); 
     }

     Public void runWait() {
        JFrame wait = waitDialog();
     wait.setVisisble(true);
     for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
         // Other activities
         System.out.println(i);
     }
     wait.setVisisble(false);
         }

I have reworked this extensively, and cannot understand why the JPanel text fails to display ONLY when I am calling the dialog through an ActionEvent.
What am I missing here?

You can't do it like that anyway. You have an incomplete picture of how Swing threading works. Have a look at the excellently documented SwingWorker and it will give you some ideas about how to accomplish what you want

After additional research, I can see that this comment from @g00se is the correct response, but I unable to select it since it is not posted as an answer.

You can't do it like that anyway. You have an incomplete picture of how Swing threading works. Have a look at the excellently documented SwingWorker and it will give you some ideas about how to accomplish what you want

The action (e.g. a button press) is executed by a special thread, the AWT-EventQueue. The same thread that is responsible for drawing the whole Frame. If you allow the function to finish drawing your JFrame and closing it after the delay in another thread, your code should work.
public void runWait() {
    JFrame wait = waitDialog();
    wait.setVisible(true);
    closeFrameDelayed(wait);
}

static void closeFrameDelayed(JFrame frame) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000); // Wait 2 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // No error handling (or printing) is bad error handling,
            // but that is out of scope here, i guess
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally {
            // SwingUtilities.invokeLater pushes the comand to the AWT-EventQueue
            // This is required, because AWT/Swing methods are not thread safe
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                frame.setVisible(false);
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

That being said it is generally not a good idea to spawn multiple frames (see The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?).
As g00se states in the comment the main issue is you are performing heavy, blocking tasks in the UI thread. Try to execute your slow "activity" logic in a separate thread and call SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> frame.setVisible(false)); when that is done.

Better use a JDialog instead. Actually using a JDialog might ironically show up the real situation. Because then the "Other activities" will not be executed until the dialog is closed ;)

@g00se that is just an option (the default one, though). setModal(false) does the trick. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal-boolean- or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html for newer java versions

Yes, I'm aware of setModal and I predicted that you would cite that ;) The point is that your answer is working against the proper coordination of threading as the heavy "Other activities" shouldn't be being performed in the main thread anyway. They should be performed in a dedicated thread that coordinates with the Event Dispatch Thread. Your "Wait 2 seconds" approach is entirely arbitrary and uncoordinated

@g00se You are right, recommending a JDialog without knowing the exact context might be misleading. I removed that line and added a hint on the main issue with the "other activities" in the event queue. I concur "wait 2 seconds" is arbitrary. It serves just as an example.
